# Uncheck checkbox after removal from array

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I'm having a weird problem with my checkboxes. It might have a simple solution because I'm new on Angular but I've tried to fix it in so many ways and I had no success.

I'm trying to do a TO DO list Google-wise. 
The problem is I have a list of itens with checkboxes and when I check one of them I want to delete the item from the array but when I do that the next item from the list is being checked.

There is the code I wrote:

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []); 
app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.todoList = [];
    $scope.doneList = [];

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {
        $scope.todoList.push({text:$scope.todoInput, done:false});
        $scope.todoInput = "";
    };

    $scope.markAsDone = function() {
        var task = $scope.todoList[this.$index];
        task.done = true;
        $scope.doneList.push(task);
        $scope.todoList.splice(this.$index, 1);
    };

    $scope.markAsTodo = function () {
        var task = $scope.doneList[this.$index];
        task.done = false;
        $scope.todoList.push(task);
        $scope.doneList.splice(this.$index, 1);
    };
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="task in todoList track by $index">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Done" ng-checked="checked" ng-click="markAsDone()">
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{task.text}}">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
  </div>
</ul>
<form class="form-group" ng-submit="todoAdd()">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="todoInput" placeholder="New Task" autofocus>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

There is an example that couldn't work. Add these tasks:
1
2
3

After that mark 2 as done, that will do 2 be removed but 3 will be checked. Always the next one will be checked.

Sorry, I couldn't make the snippet work but the code is there. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's happeneing because ng-checked will be always true, you need to update it based on the done field of the task.

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []); 
app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.todoList = [];
    $scope.doneList = [];

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {
        $scope.todoList.push({text:$scope.todoInput, done:false});
        $scope.todoInput = "";
    };

    $scope.markAsDone = function(task) {
        task.done = false;
        $scope.doneList.push(task);
        $scope.todoList.splice(this.$index, 1);
    };

    $scope.markAsTodo = function () {
        var task = $scope.doneList[this.$index];
        task.done = false;
        $scope.todoList.push(task);
        $scope.doneList.splice(this.$index, 1);
    };
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="todoCtrl"> 
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="task in todoList track by $index">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <input nng-checked="!task.done" type="checkbox" aria-label="Done"  ng-click="markAsDone(task)">
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{task.text}}">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
    {{variable}}
  </div>
</ul>
<form class="form-group" ng-submit="todoAdd()">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="todoInput" placeholder="New Task" autofocus>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sadly the problem still happens. For example, if I add the itens:
1
2
3
then I check 2, the item 2 is deleted as expected but 3 will be marked even if its done property is still false.

Comment: @MateusLuna no did you check the demo

Comment: I checked @Sajeetharan. Try to run my example, please.